# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to run the below code which uses an external library and it keeps giving me the error `"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"`.  I can't seem to figure out why as the code looks fine.  Can someone please take a look at it?  Am I supposed to write the functions for each of those variables such as `pageLoadListener`, `copyPasteListerner` etc?  I am trying to make an API call to receive some information back but it keeps giving me that error and I'm not sure if I need to define those event listeners.

```js
<script src="https://prod.rtymgt.com/static/js/review/sc_review_lib_secured_v1-2.min.js?v=1.0.1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var pageLoadListener = function(time, error) {
       // returns
       //-------------------------------------
       // time  - unencoded page load time detected
       // error - if error(string) is returned  
       
    }      
    var copyPasteListener = function(pastedText, error) {
       // returns
       //-------------------------------------
       // pastedText  - unencoded pasted text 
       // error - if error(string) is returned          
    }
    var textEventListener = function(answerTime, error) {
       // returns
       //-------------------------------------
       // answerTime  - unencoded time detected when text is typed
       // error - if error(string) is returned   
    }           
    var submitEventListener = function(submitTime, error) {
       // returns
  //-------------------------------------
       // submitTime  - unencoded time detected on submit
       // error - if error(string) is returned   
    }        
    window.onload = function() {


      var objElement  = {
          textElementId              : '[text_element_id]'   
        , pastedTextElementId        : '[encoded_pasted_text_element_id]'
        , pageLoadTextTimeElementId  : 
                               '[encoded_page_load_time_text_element_id]' 
        , entryStartTextTimeElementId: 
                                   '[encoded_typed_time_text_element_id]'     
        , submitTextTimeElementId    : 
                                  '[encoded_submit_time_text_element_id]'    
        , submitButtonElementId      : '[submit_button_id]'                       
      };   
              
      try {
         new scReviewLib(
            'https://prod.rtymgt.com' 
                                   
          , '20655122-22e6-4af3-a66c-0adb885ae5f1' // client’s publishable key on environment
          ,  objElement         // Object Element defined above
          ,  pageLoadListener
          ,  copyPasteListener 
          ,  textEventListener
          ,  submitEventListener);
   
      } catch (e) { 
         document.write(e)
      }       
    }         
</script>

<script>
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "https://prod.rtymgt.com/api/v4/respondents/review/20655122-22e6-4af3-a66c-0adb885ae5f1?q_id=TEST&text=#v_1170#", true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.send();

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);

    function processRequest(e) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        let response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        console.log(response);

        }
    }
</script>
```

I'm expecting to make an API call and receive the response but instead, it is catching the error in the try and catch block and printing the error `"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"` to the page.

Comment: You can use xhr.onreadystatechange

Comment: Thanks for your response.  So am I supposed to leave the pageLoadListener function as is?  Or do I need to define the function and return something?